# How to send a file from Unity scene to my friend

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine

So I have such a problem. I have coloured a vehicle in Unity scene and I need to send coloured version to my friend. I tried to save this file in prefab but after opening it on my friend's computer all coloures disapeeared. I tried to create an .unitypackage file but the result is the same. What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: You have really lucky friend :) Most likely you have a problem with the material. Check the material of models in both projects.

Comment: When you say all colors disappeared (for materials), does it default to a bright pink? That means it's missing some sort of reference.

Comment: @Eliasar year, there is a bright pink color...

Answer (score 1):

Create the prefab, now right click it in the explorer and select dependencies it will highlight all dependencies, right-click again and export package

Comment: Namely: the material or texture was not included because they are separate assets.

Answer (score 0):

If you are exporting .fbx models in a .unitypackage, you should convert them to prefabs first. They will definitely keep their references as prefabs.

Source: [Unity Answers](https://answers.unity.com/questions/33361/problem-importing-assets-from-a-unitypackage.html)